# Get Distinct Column Name in List

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a SQL Query like this

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CustomerName FROM  Customers
```

It is returning list of distinct customerNames,

How can I get this in list in C#

Currently I am getting the result in DataTable and then extract in list for only my required column.

```
private List<String> GetDistinctCustomerNames()
{
   var dataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");
   using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
   {
      // set the connection for the commnad
       sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

       // assign the insert query as a text to the sql command
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT  DISTINCT CustomerName FROM  Customers";

        using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
           sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
           dataTable.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader());
        }

        if (dataTable.Columns.Contains("CustomerName"))
        {
           return (from DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows select dataRow["CustomerName"].ToString()).ToList();
        }

  return null;
}
```

but I don't feel it is a good solution.

Comment: If you add Dapper you could do something like this:  IList<DomainClass> MyList = Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<DomainClass>(
                                sqlConnnection, "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName FROM Customers;").ToList();

Comment: What's wrong with using simple SqlDataReader?

Comment: You could receive the output as XML and use an XML parser to create the list for you. Perhaps more elegant though maybe not as efficient.

Comment: Better options are suggested in this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613192/c-sharp-fill-generic-list-from-sqldatareader)

Comment: Thanks @Baga, The Answer by Darin Dimitrov in the link you posted was something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should more [googling](https://www.google.sk/search?q=distinct+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:sk:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=FgjRU5PuNKH8ygOGu4KQCw#channel=fflb&q=linq+distinct+c%23&rls=org.mozilla:sk:official)  OR 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19406319/2089368  ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your return for that I would do a foreach

```
ForEach(var element in DataTable.Rows)
   if(element.CustomerName != NULL)
      list.add(element.ToString()) 
      //To string is only needed if the db stores it as not an nvarchar or something like that

return list
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the list from the method, you can apply the below code.

```
 // Get distinct elements and convert into a list again.
List<string> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I will get a Distinct List Only from SQL because of my Distinct Query, I wanted to avoid DataTable iteration.

Comment: @Pankaj.  Try this link, please combine top 1 and distinct together.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086243/sql-server-top1-with-distinct